# Calculate distance between two latitude-longitude points with SQLite (almost Haversine formula)

Tags: sqlite, dictionary, math, distance, haversine

Recently I started a project where I need to calculate the distance between two points given their latitude and longitude and select and order the points by distance.
The logical step to do this is to use the [Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula):

> Distance = 2 * R * ASIN( SQRT( SIN( (RADIANS(lat1)-RADIANS(lat2))/2 )^2 + COS( RADIANS(lat1) )*COS( RADIANS(lat2) )*SIN( (RADIANS(long1)-RADIANS(long2))/2 )^2 ) )

This is not a problem for MySQL DB, but for some reasons I needed to use SQLITE database and I was building my project with Laravel.

The problem with SQLITE is that has few math functions, and none trigonometric functions (sin, cos, etc.)

At first I thought of using SQLITE extensions, but it seems that PDO that is used by Laravel for DB connections does not allow to load them.

Then I tried PHP createFunction to define functions in SQLite, but, as far as I understand it only works with scalars, that means it does not accept fields names as argument of the defined functions.

I was stucked.

I needed to work with small distances (less than 20km) and I did not need high precision. So a plane geometry was enough for me, but how?

At last, I remembered that `sin(angle) ~ angle` if angle is small. So I went through the Haversine formula trying to simplify it. It seems a spherical solution of the Pythagorean theorem.

It is done by two parts, the first one defines the difference in latitude, let's say the Y.

```
Y = R * ABS(RADIANS(lat1)-RADIANS(lat2))
```

The second part defines the difference in longitude, let's say the X.

```
X = R * COS(RADIANS(lat0)) * ABS(RADIANS(long1)-RADIANS(long2))
```

In this part there is a COS since the radius of the circle changes with the latitude. It could be a problem since I said that SQLite does not have that function, but since we are using small variations of the angles lat0 can be a constant value, and calculated once for ever.

Since I have one point given by the user I can put `lat0 = lat1` and calculate COS(lat1) before the query or you can define it for your location.

The last thing is to calculate the `Estimated_Distance^2 = X^2 + Y^2`. Well, SQLite does not even have the SQRT functions, so you must keep it elevated by 2...

The final formula is:

> Estimated_Distance = SQRT ( ( R * ABS(RADIANS(lat1)-RADIANS(lat2)) ) ^ 2 + ( R * COS(RADIANS(lat0)) * ABS(RADIANS(long1)-RADIANS(long2)) ) ^ 2 )

The result is not too bad, the error against the Haversine formula is less than 1 m when the distance is less than 10-15 km, but it grows fast with higher distances.

When I will move the project on a production server I'll use MySQL and the correct formula, in the meanwhile this is good enough for me.

If you have any suggestion to improve it, please let me know.

I hope this can help.

Comment: It looks like PHP PDO supports [user defined functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreatefunction.php) for sqlite. You can't just create a few to provide the needed functionality?

Comment: Thank you. I tried the sqliteCreateFunction but I get the error "sqrt() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given" (for any function I define). This made me think that defined functions only accept scalars and not db fields names.

Comment: Sqlite functions take column values by name... They'd be pretty much useless if they didn't.

Comment: Note from the future: sqlite to have math functions (unless disabled during compilation): https://www.sqlite.org/lang_mathfunc.html . Also there's no point using custom formulas on mysql now as there's `ST_DISTANCE()` and `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE()` available.